# HTML hide window while waiting for server

Tags: php, html

I have an html form that has an action set to a php script on my server.  That script makes webservice requests and takes a few seconds to run.  That php script then has an html body that has the onload property set to close the window.  The idea is that after the user submits the form the window is closed and the request is sent off to the server.  However since there is that few seconds of delay the user clicks submit and then it just hangs until all the webservices complete and then the php script closes the window as expected.

I'm looking to just make it look as if it goes faster by maybe hiding the window right as they hit submit without waiting for the php script to finish.  Is there any way to do this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data would not have been submitted if it immediately closes. You can try client-side javascript to do this.

Comment: If this is a popup that's opened by another page on your site, you may be able to use javascript (`window.parent`) to do the submission from the parent page. That way, closing the popup wouldn't interrupt the processing. If you use AJAX, the parent page wouldn't have to reload or anything.

Comment: There's a user comment in the php manual describing a way to get the browser to disconnect but keep the script running on the server. http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php#104541 (There are other ways using process control or system commands, too, but this is simple, if it works...) I haven't tried it, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I supppose you could redirect to a page that has a gif that says loading and on THAT page do the processing. It is probably what i would do.

I'm not sure what you mean by "hiding the window" maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494705/continuing-to-hide-html-input-fields-when-page-refreshes) is what you are talking about.

If you mean minimizing the window, firstly, why? secondly, i'm not sure you can do this and if you can it will probably be in javascript(client side code)

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  If you close your window any earlier, there's a possibility you may not receive a complete request to process I suspect.

Not sure why you would even close the browser window.  In most tabbed browsers, the effect of closing a window is negligible.

If it's your own popup window you're closing, you could target the form submission to the parent window and the popup window could then close faster I guess.

I'm not completely up to speed with the possibilities of PHP, but if you're not interested in sending the web service results to the browser, then you can maybe put them on a separate job/thread/process (whatever) and respond before waiting for them to complete?

Answer (score 0):

When you have sent the formdata to the webservice, the rest will happen on the server therefore you should be able to move the onload script to the onclick event of the button.

Something like

```
<input type="Button" onclick="document.thisform.submit();window.close();" value="Click" />
```

this is written by head so it might contain some errors.

Comment: The [default behavior of php](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php) is to abort the script when the client disconnects, though it can be altered.